# Print values from an SQL database table with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am new at PHP/SQL so bear with me if I say something that's obvious or downright wrong.
I have a SQL table (in a database) and I need to take 3 random values (name, race, year), each from a different field in the table, and print it on a website with php. The value requirement "race" will be different depending on radiobuttons (lets say RB1, and RB2) and this all has to happen when

`<input type="submit" name="button">` is clicked.

```
<html>  <input type="radio" name="RB1"> Asian  </html>
```

What could I do in this situation?

Example: So if RB1 is selected and the button is clicked I will need to randomly print a "name" with the corresponding "year" (of the name) and it should have a corresponding race of RB1 (which is Asian)

Comment: use jquery/ajax for this (instant result display kinda thing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this code will help you to understand this-

DB thing, you have to take care for that..im giving you an idea to handle this sort of stuff.

Create one test.php file(this what i did)

Place this code --

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>index</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("input:radio[name=race]").change(function(){
$.ajax({
type : 'GET',
url : 'getdata.php',
data: {race : $('input:radio[name=race]:checked').val()},
success: function(data){
$('#showdata').html(data);
},
});
});
});
</script>
</head>

<body>

<form action="#" method="post" name="myform">
<input type="radio" name="race" value="RB1" /> Asian
<input type="radio" name="race" value="RB2" /> European 
</form>

<div id="showdata"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

In getdata.php file paste this content -

```
<?php

$myvalue = $_GET['race'];

if( $myvalue == 'RB1')
{
echo "I am RB1";
}
if( $myvalue == 'RB2')
{
echo "I am RB2";
}
```

Run the code in browser now (test.php).